# Is it possible to recognise tracking face?

Tags: android-vision

Using `Mobile vision` Face API we can recognize faces.. But is it possible to define image set and try to compare tracking face and images from set and recognize tracking image in result?

If yes could you please give some hint how i can organize it or add some additional tools for it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the mobile vision face API does not support facial recognition.

Although it does support tracking faces in video, the tracking mechanism uses position/size/velocity correlation to track faces from frame to frame, and does not use a facial similarity metric.